# Would not send mail from other than Mail apps

Tags: ipad, mail.app, mobile-mail

I often want to share links in Safari via Mail. I usually share (button next to the address bar) and click on Mail and send it to the person of my choice.

[image]

But, since I updated to iPadOS 16 (December 2022), it doesn't work anymore from out-of-Mail. I mean that when I try to send mail from any other app than Mail by sharing, it does show the send options (as if drafting a normal email), everything seems to work fine, I compose, I send. **But** the email never gets sent! I checked in my "Sent" mailbox, where the emails I've sent normally go to, but the one I've tried sending isn't there, even an hour after.

When I send the same email (same email/person/sender/subject...) from Mail app, it works just fine, I just have to wait for about 10-20 seconds to get the email to be loaded in the "Sent" mailbox.

**How to make me able to send email from any app again?**

*Note : I am on iPad 6th generation running iPadOS 16.2*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Disable Undo Send Delay

This is a weird behavior for Mail on iPad. The only way I've found to avoid having this problem is to diable Undo Send Delay, a new feature that came with iPadOS 16 that made you able to retract a sent email (so obviously not sent yet) to avoid accidental sending, in Settings :

1. Open **Settings** app
2. Navigate to "**Mail**"
3. At the bottom of the menu, under "Signature", click on "**Undo Send Delay**".
4. Click on "**Off**"

[image]

For an unknown reason, the Undo Send Delay makes sending from other apps impossible. It is normal you have to wait 10-20 seconds because the Undo Send Delay was parametered by default to be 10s.

This works for me, I can now send anything I want from another app by clicking on Share.

Good luck!

Comment: That seems an  oddly specific and completely unrelated setting.  I use three different mail clients and cannot replicate your issue even with the Send Delay set to 20 seconds.

Comment: @Allan Are you on iPad? And are you using the Share button (next to the address bar in Safari or long-press on a file and share in Files for ex.)? Also, my friends were experiencing the same problem as I did (same iPad and same OS update).

Comment: Yes.  iPad 6th gen. Though that would have no bearing on the issue.  It’s likely your other mail clients also have a send delay configured.  Can you share using messages?

Comment: Hm. This is indeed weird @Allan . Are you using an iCloud account for Mail? If not what are you using? I can use messages for sharing but there's no send delay there I think.

Comment: All of that is irrelevant.  Mail delay is a client setting

Comment: @Allan that's what I thought but my comment was a rough guess. I edited it to answer the second part of your question.